Finding Closed Form Solution
I am looking for a closed form solution to the problem
$\min_{W} \ AW - y \\$
$\text{such that} \\$
$\sum_{i} w_i \le 1 \\$
$w_i > 0 \quad \forall i \in W$
I am pretty new to optimization so I have been struggling. I think what I am suppose to do is use KKT conditions to test if it exists. I had assumed it would be I beleive that if I wanted to maximize Aw $\text{such that} \\$
$\sum_{i} W^tW \le \alpha \\$ exists and is given by the left hand singular vectors of A. This problem looked similar to me but I am not sure. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Please clarify your notation. Is $W$ the same as $w$? What are $A$ and $y$?

Sorry I shouldve have clarified W is the set of all $\omega$ A is the dataset and y is the target
